# default to relative path in workspaces/projects?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to default to using the relative path (to the workspace or project file) when creating workspace/project files and when sublime updates them when files are added or removed?

Comment: Are you using git? According to this userecho post although ST3 can handle relative paths, it won't save them, or keep them. You can however use post/pre-commit scripts to remove the absolute path.  http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/92820-shared-sublime-project-files/

Comment: Actually not commit hooks, but a clean or smudge http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion